# Python - Using gspread and tkinter live search options?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.6, gspread

I am writing a program for people to check into a meeting with a graphical interface from tkinter, and I am storing the names and other variables in google spreadsheets using gspread. My questions is whether there is a way to get a live search of the names in the spreadsheet that is populated as a person types. For example, if the spreadsheet has names: Bob, Michael, John, Steve, Sue, Susan and using a text entry box in tkinter, while a person types their name, if they type in S, then Sue, Steve, and Susan appear in some sort of window, and if they type u after S, then the list will only offer Sue and Susan for the person to select their name from. I know gspread has a search for by cell value, but is there anyway to get it to show the results as it searches?